# problems deploying monotouch develped app to ios6 via testflight but ok on ios5

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6, testflight

when i use testflight to deploy my iphone apps they work fine on ios5 but not on ios 6

they "seem" to be installing ok but eventually display a "failed message, please retry"

i am using latest version of xcode 4.5 and lasted monotouch

works fine on ios6 simulator and when i connect my mac to an ios6 device directly

I cant see anything obvious that is ios6 specific in the testflight build/permissions config

any ideas greatfully received

Answer (score 0):

This sounds just like a provisioning profile issue.

Is this new iOS 6 device setup on the provisioning profile?  This is generally the issue when I've seen this error from TestFlight in the past.

Comment: i dont think it was a provisioning issue as the app was actually delivered to the phone.

Comment: however suspecting there must be something wrong there i have created a new provisioning profile - and it now works

Comment: If the device's UUID isn't on the provisioning profile, this is what TestFlight does.  I know it is weird, it should be something that fails immediately, but I guess iOS doesn't know until the app is completely downloaded.